# Quartz.NET server documentation

Tags: .net, quartz-scheduler

when downloading Quartz.NET it contains a server component with a console application.

The website, faq and API documentation doesn't mention anything about it.

Would anybody know more about it or know where I can find more documentation on it?

Thanks,
Patrick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you can join [Quartz.NET Google group](http://groups.google.com/group/quartznet) and ask questions or read archives. I'm successfully using quartz server-client with remote scheduling from client, all that I needed I learned from downloaded code samples.

Comment: Where do i find the code samples please as they aren't included in the default download?
Thanks,
Patrick

Comment: In downloaded Quartz.NET-1.0.1.zip file please open Quartz.2008.sln and take a look at Quartz.Examples.2008 project, there you will find example12 folder with simple client and server implementation.