# How to setup Quartz.NET for scheduling Emails

Tags: c#, asp.net, scheduled-tasks, scheduling, quartz.net

There are two solutions **Quartz.server.2008.sln** and **quartz.2008.sln** in the downloaded quartz.NET library. Now I have to setup recurring job. There would be table in the database where all schedules will be defined (like first friday of the month, each 5 in month, each sunday 12 am...etc). I have the method executed on schedule. Now how can i use quartz.net to get schedule  from database and set the method to execute? what are the proper steps?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can create a windows service running in background. You can read the `scheduleFromDatabase` varaible from database and then pass it to Quartz.

This is a small example from a console app:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ISchedulerFactory schedFact = new StdSchedulerFactory();

        IScheduler sched = schedFact.GetScheduler();
        sched.Start();

        JobDetail jobDetail = new JobDetail("myJob", null, typeof(HelloJob));

        //read this string from database
        string scheduleFromDatabase="0 11 16 ? * FRI,SUN";

        CronTrigger trigger = new CronTrigger("trigger1", null, "myJob",
                                                null,scheduleFromDatabase );

        trigger.StartTimeUtc = DateTime.UtcNow;
        trigger.Name = "myTrigger";
        sched.ScheduleJob(jobDetail, trigger); 
    }

public class HelloJob:IJob
{

    public void Execute(JobExecutionContext context)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString());
        //Call here your method!
    }
}
```

This can be useful:

[Quartz.NET server documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1004133/735864)

Answer (score 2):

The quartz documentation does seem to assume that everyone knows the basics and is only looking for details.

Hopefully the steps below, along with the Quartz documentation and samples, you'll be able to get your project started.

Step 1: Open Windows Explorer to the ...\Quartz.NET-1.0.3\database\tables folder
Step 2: Execute the script appropriate for your database
Step 3: Open Windows Explorer to the ...\Quartz.NET-1.0.3\server\bin\3.5\console folder
Step 4: Create a class library assembly and add a class that implements the IJob interface.
Step 5: Edit the quartz.config file.  Mine is below.

```
  ################################################################################
  # Added by Brad Bruce
  # please refer to http://quartznet.sourceforge.net/tutorial/lesson_9.html before making changes
  ################################################################################
  quartz.jobStore.type = Quartz.Impl.AdoJobStore.JobStoreTX, Quartz
  quartz.jobStore.driverDelegateType = Quartz.Impl.AdoJobStore.OracleDelegate, Quartz
  quartz.jobStore.tablePrefix = QRTZ_
  quartz.jobStore.dataSource = myDS
  quartz.dataSource.myDS.connectionString = Data Source=xe; User Id=quartz; Password=quartz;
  quartz.dataSource.myDS.provider = OracleODP-20
  quartz.jobStore.useProperties = true
```

Step 6: Run the console server and verify that the dummy job is running
Step 7: Copy the console project to a new project
Step 8: Modify the console source to schedule the job via the Quartz API.  You will be able to reuse this project to schedule other jobs.

If they would only add a project to schedule and manage the jobs, I think Quartz.Net would really take off.

Comment: Does it take schedule information from database? I have a separate table where all schedules and jobname are defined. Can i dynamically add jobs from table or  will it automatically pickup if i update the quartz tables.

Comment: Without creating your own job store, you're pretty much restricted to using their tables.  Updates should be done through their API and not directly against the database. (It usually doesn't go smoothly do update the tables directly)