# Send Email to admin at specific time everyday / be notified when stock levels are low by email

Tags: c#, asp.net

Does anyone know how i would code this:

to send an email to the admin/manager everyday at a specific time including a table from the database (Stock Table - which only has four pieces of stock) so they will be informed of their stock levels and if they need to reorder.

Or else

Something in which will send an email to the manager/ admin if one of these four stock levels are low informing them a certin materials/ piece of stock has reached the minimum level and to re order.

I have the code for sending an email:

```
protected void Button1_Click1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
MailMessage mail = new MailMessage(from.Text, to.Text, subject.Text, body.Text);
SmtpClient Client = new SmtpClient(smtp.Text);
Client.Port = 587;
Client.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(username.Text, password.Text);
Client.EnableSsl = true;
Client.Send(mail);
Response.Write("<script LANGUAGE='JavaScript' >alert('Mail Sent')</script>");
}
```

any help is welcomed!!!

Thank you!

Comment: You can check Quartz.NET for scheduled service task. see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6647272/how-to-setup-quartz-net-for-scheduling-emails

Comment: Consider searching for something like 'scheduling asp.net code to run'

Comment: you just need an automated process of some kind which runs on a scheduled basis (i.e. at specific pre-defined intervals) and checks whether an email needs to be sent, and if so, sends one. Lots of different ways to actually achieve that, you can research it easily enough.

Answer (score 0):

You need a scheduler so you can schedule a daily task to check the stock levels and send an email if needed. You can achieve this using hangfire if you want to keep everything inside your asp.net application. Hangfire is a scheduler. Check https://www.hangfire.io/

The code would look like this

```
RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate(
() => {
//TODO: Check your Stock Table DB
var from = "noreply@<yourcompany>.com"
var to = "admin@<yourcompny>.com"
var subject = "Low stock"
var body = "The following items are low in stock : "
// TODO: append items to body variable
MailMessage mail = new MailMessage(from, to, subject, body);

SmtpClient Client = new SmtpClient(smtp.Text);
Client.Port = 587;
Client.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(username.Text, password.Text);
Client.EnableSsl = true;
Client.Send(mail);},
    Cron.Daily);
});
```

Comment: thank you very much! where would this code go? under a button or page load of the stock form that displays the table.

Comment: You can add this code on your Global.asax

protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
// add code here
}

Comment: thank you very much! would you know how to use a loop to check if any of the 4 materials in my stock table in my database have reached minimum level (i will set it at 200) ? thank you kindly

Comment: you should mark this question and answer and create a new question

Answer (score 0):

use Windows Service to Monitoring the data, hour and DB.

```
    private void mainTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            if (ConfigsHTM["exechour"] != null)
            {
                if (DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss") == ConfigsHTM["exechour"].ToString())
                {
                    ClassProcessing clsProc = new ClassProcessing();
                    clsProc.StartDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1);
                    clsProc.EndDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1);
                    clsProc.ProcessAll();

                    if (StatusHTM.Count > 0)
                        StatusHTM.Clear();

                    StatusHTM.Add("locationstatus","Todas as Unidades");
                    StatusHTM.Add("typestatus","Agendado");

                    StatusHTM.Add("exechourstatus", DateTime.Now.ToString("F"));

                    if (clsProc.ReprocessingDone)
                        StatusHTM.Add("statusstatus","OK");
                    else
                        StatusHTM.Add("statusstatus", "Falhou");

                    ClassStatus clsStt = new ClassStatus();
                    clsStt.StatusHT = StatusHTM;
                    clsStt.SaveStatus();
                    GetStatus();
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ClassLog clsLog = new ClassLog();
            clsLog.EventData = "Falha ao Iniciar a Execução do  Aplicativo";
            clsLog.ErrorLog();
            clsLog.EventData = ex.ToString();
            clsLog.ErrorLog();
        }
    }
```